# Cannot retrieve data from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have an application,which is not able to fetch data from the database for this specific form, while other forms are working fine.

I am using this form to fetch data from database and then display that data onto labels on an another form.

The code for fetching data is:

```
string PName, DName, Psex, PPhoneNo, PAddress, Treatment, Teethno, PAge, Amount;

SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("Select bills.BillNo,bills.PName,bills.DName,bills.PAge,bills.PSex,bills.PPhoneNo,bills.PAddress,bills.Treatment,bills.Amount,bills.Teethno,addpro.Medicines from bills,addpro where bills.BillNo=" + bno, Program.con);

DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
PAge = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[3]);
Amount = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[8]);
PName = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[1]);
DName = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[2]);
Psex = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[4]);
PPhoneNo = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[5]);
PAddress = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[6]);
Treatment = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[7]);
Teethno = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[9]);

frmPrint sa=new frmPrint();
sa.start(bno, PAge, Amount, PName, DName, Psex, PPhoneNo, PAddress, Treatment,  Teethno);
```

when i try to load the next form which displays the data from this `DataTable` on labels it gives the following error:-

> There is no row at position 3.

Comment: Please don't use the old style of joins: "from bills,addpro where".  Use the new style: "from bills INNER JOIN addpro ON ...".  It's been in the ANSI SQL standards since 1992.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're using Row and you want to be using Column:

```
foreach(DataRow row in t.Rows)
{
        PAge = row["PAge"].ToString();
        Amount = row["Amount"].ToString();
        PName = row["PName"].ToString();
        DName = row["DName"].ToString();
        Psex = row["PSex"].ToString();
        PPhoneNo = row["PPhoneNo"].ToString();
        PAddress = row["PAddress"].ToString();
        Treatment = row["Treatment"].ToString();
        Teethno = row["Teethno"].ToString();
}
```

Instead of using the number to identify the column, use the name.  If the order of the query was to change for any reason, this would not have an impact on your code.  If you used the Ordinal number, then you would need to change your row[n] code too since the order would have changed.

Comment: Thank You.
Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing different rows for each field.
You should access the first row and then different columns:

```
t.Rows[0].Columns[0]
t.Rows[0].Columns[1]
t.Rows[0].Columns[2]
t.Rows[0].Columns[3]
...
```

Comment: giving error that System.Data.Datarow doesnot contain definition for Columns

Comment: I'm not sure on how the actual property is called, but that's the concept. The other answers should have the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use `[Columns]`

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
PAge = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[0]["ColumnsName"]);  
// and so on
```

Comment: giving error that System.Data.Datarow doesnot contain definition for Columns

Comment: try using columnname directly